# OmniAuth ruby on rails, forcing facebook user to re-authenticate when currently logged into facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I have a facebook application that the user has authorized. I want to re-authenticate when their token has expired. The problem is that when the user is already logged in to Facebook, and they have already authorized the application, facebook just redirects back to the redirect_url. I don't want this behavior as the user may have multiple facebook accounts and the one they're logged in to may not be the correct one.
The initial facebook authorization happens via server side authentication.

**I want to either:**

- pick which one [account] to authenticate with (this is ideal) or
- force them to re-authenticate their facebook credentials

I would like to avoid using the javascript sdk to force logout then re-login in if possible. I would like to keep everything server side for maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can [configure omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring) to force reauthentication by setting `auth_type` to `reauthenticate`.

Comment: How would you go about setting the auth_type to reauthenticate using omniauth?

Comment: Figured it out: `redirect_to '/users/auth/facebook?auth_type=reauthenticate'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to force to re-authenticate users. ( that would be the better solution ) But It's the first time I hear someone who wants the token expires faster. (Token last 2 hours, https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/ ).

Your use case it's really unusual:

"*the user may have multiple facebook accounts and the one they're logged in to may not be the correct one*"

Who has multiple Facebook accounts?
Maybe if your are a developer, you will need an extra account, but it's better to use this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Regards

Ivangrx

Comment: anyone that manages accounts for businesses and/or other people have more than one account.

Comment: I have like 5 Facebook accounts

Answer (score 1):

> force them to re-authenticate their facebook credentials

The OAuth dialog offers a method for [Re-Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/) – but I’m not quite sure if that fits your needs, so you’ll have to give it a try.